# Scrapy generate csv file (UTF-8)

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, scrapy

I try to generate a CSV file with the result of the crawler. Because it is German, I need to have it UTF-8 encoded (ä,ö, etc.). This is my result so far:

spider.py

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Polizeimeldungen.items import PolizeimeldungenItem


class PoliceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "pm"
  allowed_domains = ["berlin.de"]
  start_urls = 
["https://www.berlin.de/polizei/polizeimeldungen/archiv/2014/?page_at_1_0=1"]

  def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.css('.row-fluid'):
        item = PolizeimeldungenItem()
        item['title'] = sel.css('a ::text').extract_first().encode('utf-8')
        item['link'] = sel.css('a ::text').extract_first().encode('utf-8') // this is wrong, but it is easy to fix  
        yield item
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

class PolizeimeldungenItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
import csv
class PolizeimeldungenPipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.myCsv = csv.writer(open('Item.csv', 'wb'))
    self.myCsv.writerow(['title', 'link'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):          
        self.myCsv.writerow([item['title'], item['link']])
        return item
```

Settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'Polizeimeldungen'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Polizeimeldungen.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Polizeimeldungen.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'Polizeimeldungen.pipelines.PolizeimeldungenPipeline': 100}
```

AS the result after:

```
scrapy crawl pm
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Thanks for your help!!

UPDATE: Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1

Comment: Any specific reason why you simply don't use the builtin csv serialization by using `scrapy crawl pm -o output_file.csv` ?

Comment: Also it seems the csv lib used in your custom built output pipeline needs some tweaking to do utf-8 output: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: @rrschmidt This only applies to Python 2. Apparently (and that's a good thing), the OP is working with Python 3, otherwise the TypeError message would make no sense (in Python 2 `str` *is* a bytes-like object).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Python 3 (this solution won't work with Python 2).

You need to change two things:

- Open the output file in text mode, with the desired output encoding.
  In the `PolizeimeldungenPipeline`'s constructor, write:

  ```
  self.myCsv = csv.writer(open('Item.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8'))
  ```
- Don't encode the cells (as in `PoliceSpider.parse`):

  ```
  item['title'] = sel.css('a ::text').extract_first()
  ```

  etc.

Comment: Thanks, @lenz valid points! It works without an error, but the CSV file is still empty :(

Comment: So far, you haven't mentioned that the output is empty. It's most probably a different problem.